# Validation Failing for Valid Hashref

Tags: perl, moose, hashref, moosex-types

I'm deploying my software (first time in a new environment) and hitting a wall almost immediately.

I have a value that is failing its HashRef validation, but every test I can think of makes it seem like it should be valid.

> Attribute (store) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'HashRef' with value MyApp::CatalystAuthStore=HASH(0x7fa98fffa590)...

Dumping that value produces a valid-looking hashref:

```
bless( {
     'config' => {
                   'class' => '+MyApp::CatalystAuthStore',
                   'use_userdata_from_session' => 1
                 }
   }, 'MyApp::CatalystAuthStore' )
```

And when I try to self-validate using Scalar::Util::Reftype, it returns 'HASH' for my value.

So if for a moment, we could rule out an issue with my code, and considering that this is occuring for the first time at deployment, what is a good way to see what part of Moose isn't working properly on my build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashRef` specifically looks for a unblessed hash, but yours is blessed (a MyApp::CatalystAuthStore object). Maybe `MyApp::CatalystAuthStore` would be a more appropriate type to use? If not, you could easily create a type that accepts both blessed and unblessed hashes.

```
subtype 'AnyHashRef'
   => as 'Defined'
   => where { Scalar::Util::reftype($_) eq 'HASH' }
   => inline_as { "( Scalar::Util::reftype($_[1]) eq 'HASH' )" };
```

Comment: I may never understand why it always worked in my test environment during development, but you are completely correct.